# How to apply IE11 specific css

Tags: css, extjs, ie11-developer-tools

I am new user for IE11.
  I want to integrate one IE11 specific css in my extjs application.
  I have searched a lot.
  If anybody is having any idea , please let me know..I am having heavy deadline on this.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    applyIEFont = function() {
        var iev=0;
        var ieold = (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent));
        var trident = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0/);
        var rv=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11.0");

        if (ieold) iev=new Number(RegExp.$1);
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") != -1) iev=10;
        if (trident&&rv!=-1) iev=11;

        if(iev == 11 || iev == 10) {
            $('.menuCaption').css({ font: 'normal 34px arial, "SegoeUi"'});
        }
    };

    setInterval(applyIEFont, 300);
    $(document).ready(applyIEFont);
```

look this code. Conditional comments doesn't work in ie11, so you have to do it with js

Comment: I just want to add margin to my component

Comment: then change this row
$('.menuCaption').css({ font: 'normal 34px arial, "SegoeUi"'});
with
$(<your element id or class>).css({ margin: 'left/right...'});

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to detect IE 11 and apply CSS classes accordingly.  Something like this (using jQuery):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv:11\./)) {
    $('body').addClass('ie11');
  }
});
```

You can apply that class to any element that you know you have IE 11 exceptions then just use the class in your CSS like so:

```
body.ie11 { }
```

Comment: With ExtJS 4.2.2 (and above) you can also use [`Ext.isIE11`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-property-isIE11) to detect IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two steps solution 
here is a hack to IE10 and 11

```
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
}
```

because IE10 and IE11 Supports -ms-high-cotrast you can take the advantage of this to target this two browsers

and if you want to exclude the IE10 from this you must create a IE10 specific code as follow it's using the user agent trick you must add this Javascript

```
 var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

and this HTML tag

```
<html data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">
```

and now you can write your CSS code like this

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

for more information please refer to this websites,number one:[wil tutorail](http://www.limecanvas.com/css-hacks-targeting-ie-10/)

number two:[Chris Tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/)

Comment: thanks for your humble help..But I want to apply css only for IE11..It is applying css on IE10 also...Any solution for that? -k.shree

Comment: Actually As I said before,this could be done by a trick,you will use the first method for applying styles to IE11,but by using this method the styles will be apply to IE10 to,but after using the second method you can override the styles which,you have been applied to IE10,this is like excluding the IE10 when you are using this method.this is kind of tricky.